# Regular expression match string with wildcard

Tags: java, typescript

I have a string with the following format: 'val1/val2/val3/val4'. I want a function which when comparing this string format with this string value 'val1/?/val3/?' to return true. The '?' can be any value. 
I have tried with the string include method but this doesn't cover the '?' value.How can I do this using regular expressions in javascript?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Try to find last `/` and substring both string to first `val1/val2/val3` and then compare it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try using this pattern:

```
val1/[^/]+/val3/.*
```

Sample:

```
String input = "val1/some_path/val3/stuff";
if (input.matches("val1/[^/]+/val3/.*")) {
    System.out.println("match");
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot Tim. That was what I was looking for. So the ^ means any character and + means 1 or more characters. A small fix the maches should be match instead.

Comment: The `[^/]+` term means one or more of any character which is _not_ forward slash.